# Building ajax post with jQuery each()

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion-10, cfc

I am pulling data from an excel and I want to insert that data into a database via coldfusion CFC. I do this all the time except this time I am building the "data" portion of the ajax dynamically. What is happening is when I look at the URL string its not adding the form data I built in the var xData. Everything looks right but the data is not being carried over to the CFC. Thank you in advance

Ernest Pena Jr.

Here is my Code:

```
    $.each(formulas, function(i) {
        var xData ='';
        var x = Object.keys(formulas[i]).length
        var y = 0;
        $.each(formulas[i], function(index,value) {
            var c = ''
            y++
            if(y!=x){var c = ','}
            xData += index+':'+value+''+c
        });
        $.ajax({type: "POST",url: "CFCs/"+tblName+".cfc?method="+tblName+"_FORMULA_ADD", dataType: "json",data:{xData},

            success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    });
```

results:

**Query String Parameters** view source view URL encoded

**method:** WAIS4_FORMULA_ADD

**Form Data** view source view URL encoded

xData:SCALED_SCORE:8,DDID:2581,AGE_START:16,AGE_END:17,RAW_SCORE_START:34,RAW_SCORE_END:36,ENTEREDBYID:156936,DATEENTERED:4/23/15,VERSION:1

Comment: `data:{xData}` is a syntax error. Braces surround an object, which must be of the form `key:value, key:value, etc.`

Comment: Have you tried just doing `data:formulas[i]`? I've never used ColdFusion before, but it seems like you're re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{xData}` will not parse the contents of the string `xData` as key-value pairs. You should build the object directly in the `$.each` loop, not a string.

```
xData = {};
$.each(formulas[i], function(index, value) {
    xData[index] = value;
});
```

Then use `data: xData` in the AJAX call.

But all the above loop is doing is making a copy of `formulas[i]`. You can simply use `data: formulas[i]`